# How to ignore JS and CSS files on gated checkin?

Tags: tfs, build-automation, checkin

Is there a way to avoid the automated build when we checkin only `js` or `css` files?

It doesn't need to build anything, I would like to skip the build for these files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do what you are wanting to do- I don't think gated check-ins is that mature yet.  There are quite a few outstanding enhancement requests for gated check-ins.  It might be worth adding this as a request.  Even cloaked folders are at the folder level and not the file level.

From MSDN:

> Automatically Run Gated Check-in
>   Builds
>
> A gated check-in build is run
>   automatically when either of the
>   following events occur:
>
> - A build has been defined with the Gated Check-in check box selected on
>     the Trigger tab of the build
>     definition.
> - Someone attempts to check in one or more changes that intersect with
>     any of the mapped folders in the
>     Workspace tab of the build definition.

Even if you add a *****NO_CI***** tag and try to checkin, it will stll fire the check to build changes.

The obvious workaround is of course to check the checkbox ignoring the need to do a build (a path I am sure you are trying to avoid).

If we take a look at the UI around editing a build definition, there aren't optional parameters for rules etcetera.  All that matters is the mapped folders.

You can however set specific folders to not build by cloaking a workspace folder.  However, if you do that, it will not pick up those files for builds at all.  So if you had all your JS files in one folder and excluded it from the build using the cloaked approach builds would fail when you actually wanted to run the build.